# Retrieve UserID in Cron Job Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, cron

I want to create an automated invoice data that occurs on the first day of every month. To do so, I need to pass the user data into the **invoice** table, but I cannot retrieve the user ID in **Cron Job Laravel 5.7**.
Can someone assist me in retrieving the user id?

```
use Auth;
use App\User;
use App\UserDetail;


    public function handle()
    {
        echo Auth::guard('users')->user()->id;
    }
```

Comment: Since it is a cron job there is no `Authorized` user available. You have to fetch data(id) using `eloquent`.

Comment: you can easily get it using Auth::User()->id and extends Authenticatable in user model.

Answer (score 0):

I think it won't work as there is no authenticated user available.  You may have to pass the user object to the constructor when you create the Job. Something like

```
 $theJob = new SomeJob(\Auth::user());
```

And then in your job

```
 public function __construct(User $user) {
    $this->user = $user;
}
```